# How are github action minutes calculated?

Tags: github, github-actions

After just running my workflow once, I can see 387 minutes have been used up. (Of course I checked before: 0 minutes / fresh billing cycle):

[image]

The strange thing is: In the workflow details, only 56 billable minutes are listed. I am confused. Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your usage may look like as the following:

```
Linux: 11m 13s 
Windows: 6m 36s 
MacOS: 17m 50
MacOS: 17m 51 
Linux: 36s
```

GitHub rounds the minutes and partial minutes **each job** uses up to the nearest whole minute.

So you'd end up with:

```
12 + 7 + 18 + 18 + 1
```

Which has a total of `56` billable minutes as you see in:

[image: job time vs billable minutes]

And that `30m 14s` represents the time your workflow took, it is lower than `54m 1s` of course because you have 3 jobs running in parallel.

Then comes [minutes multipliers](https://docs.github.com/en/billing/managing-billing-for-github-actions/about-billing-for-github-actions#minute-multipliers):

| Operating system | Minute multiplier |
| --- | --- |
| Linux | 1 |
| Windows | 2 |
| macOS | 10 |

I believe that you ran your first and your last jobs on Linux machines, which means you have `12 * 1 + 1 * 1 = 13`.

You have one Job running on Windows `7 * 2 = 14`. And 2 Jobs running on MacOS `18 * 2 * 10 = 360`.

The total would be `387` billable minutes you see in your billing summary page.

References:

- https://docs.github.com/en/billing/managing-billing-for-github-actions/about-billing-for-github-actions

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks so much!

Comment: this should be what they have in their docs...

Comment: Incredibly well formatted answer ⭐